# Video player with TTML support

Tags: video-player, subtitle

Is there any video player for Ubuntu that supports the TTML (Timed-Text Markup Language) subtitle format?

I have tried VLC (version 2.2.2). Neither MPlayer supports it according to its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try VLC 3.0 or more.

3.0 Features :
TTML subtitles support, including EBU-TT variant

source : https://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/3.0.0.html

I've tested it with VLC 3.0.3. It work but I had to change the file extension from .ttlm to .txt in order to be able to select the file.

TTML Subtitle Example : https://gist.github.com/anotherhale/676a72edc84ca3a37c0c